# Ubuntu 20.04 frozen, keypad and touchpad were not working, and issue persisted after force shutdown and normal boot up

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, freeze

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and dual booted on HP Pavilion 15-ck063tx laptop. I booted Ubuntu during startup and everything started up like usual. However, the screen seemed to freeze, touchpad/mouse and keyboard were all not responding [**Edited**: The screen frozen a few seconds after boot, I can see my Desktop when it is stagnant].

I couldn't use my keyboard and the terminal, so there were a lot more other solution to test and check on the issue is not possible to me right now. I have tried the following but none of them seemed working:

- `Ctrl + Alt + F1`
- Reboot with `REISUB`

The only thing that worked was the hard reboot (long press on the power button). I tried to shut it down using this method and start it up again normally, but same things happened, nothing is responding.

My laptop is hotter than usual (I think the side where HDD was located is the hottest). I can hear the fan is running though. Also, if it is worth mentioning, the last time I used Ubuntu, I updated the system with `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. I couldn't recall now on what it has been installed...

Any idea what is wrong with my laptop? Or is it possible to know what is going wrong?
What else can I do now?

[Update] It suddenly turned off while I was writing this post. The battery level was around 60%-70%. I tried starting it up again after it cooled down and it was prompting the CMOS battery error (Not the first time I saw this error prompted):
`The CMOS checksum is invalid. The CMOS will be reset to the default configuration and will be rebooted. Please check your BIOS Setup options to see if they change. CMOS Reset (502)` The CMOS battery has been long causing issue.

I pressed enter and it shut down again.

[Update 2] Well, it seemed that the battery was being drained. And I was managed to boot into Windows 10. Windows 10 worked just fine. I restarted the system and booted back to Ubuntu, and it got frozen again.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the brand and model of your computer? Do you have an Ubuntu installation USB nearby that you can use? 

Comment: Hi @matigo, thanks for the reply. I have updated the model of my computer. Yes I have the Ubuntu installation USB. But the files in my hard disk is one of my main concern too, I was yet to back up them...Also, I have some latest update on the situation.

Comment: The installation USB isn’t to reinstall, but to investigate. If you boot with the USB and choose “Try Ubuntu”, you will load a live session. From there, you can access your Ubuntu partition and try to find the reason for the boot failure. The information will be in `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/boot.log`. Take a look at those files and see if there are errors being reported. Once you know what is preventing your system from booting, it will be more likely that you can fix it 

Comment: … and further to matigo’s comment - completely agree, but even before doing that, use the live usb session to back everything up while you still can.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the input @matigo. Should I do the same if I manage to boot successfully? It doesn't seem to be boot failure to me, as I can enter Ubuntu successfully, just that it remained freeze a few seconds after Ubuntu started. I can see my Desktop on the screen when the screen frozen. My apologise if I wasn't as clear in the question.

Comment: (seems I cannot comment but answer) Not an answer, just to say I'm in the same case : Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, Dell 3793, apt update today, and always freeze a few seconds after login, hard reboot, thermal pbs too (heat + viewed in /var/log/syslog with Ctrl+Alt+F2 before logging in), lots of errors with gnome-shell too, no idea for the moment, tried creating a new user (testing generic configuration files), same behaviour ... :-(

Comment: @L1n3wb13 You can make comments after you have reached 50 reputation: https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: Hi @L1n3wb13, did you happen to encounter any workaround? I managed to backup all my important files (thanks to Will's suggestion!), but couldn't seem to get back the OS atm. Currently using another PC to run the work. Well, the plan is to re-install Ubuntu...that can be a massive task to re-install back all the softwares! Sigh!

Comment: The /var/log/syslog or /var/log/boot.log I can see, were showing the date and time where I accessed Ubuntu using the live USB, not the time when I encountered with error though...

Answer (score 0):

(41 reputations only, still not able to comment) @web, have you tried momentarily to boot using an old kernel ? It worked for me (currently booting 5.4.0-99-generic kernel), though I still haven't determine the root cause of the pb (either snd_hda_intel or nouveau driver probably).